# Angular & AngularFire | Passing variables - examples / good references?

Tags: angular, angularfire2

It seems like there is a bit of black magic (to my uneducated self) around how variables get passed around in Angular. I'm sure I am missing basic steps and would love any resources to learn the ins & outs.

I'm also missing something obvious on the html display (bonus question!)

The specific example I am struggling with (along with others) is below ([also as a StackBlitz here](https://angular-firetortbexample.stackblitz.io))

I am trying to find a field associated with a user through a database query:

```
getUID() {
      this.email$ = 'j@j.com'; //coming from auth service (this.auth.email)
      this.cdQ3 = firebase.database().ref('/ftuserprofiles').orderByChild('email').equalTo(this.email$);
      this.details = this.cdQ3.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        this.items = [];
        snapshot.forEach( snap => {
            this.uid2 = snap.key;

                    console.log('cid from getUID-garden : ' + this.uid2);
                    return false;
                  });
      });
      return this.uid2;
    }
```

This should return an id (uid2) that I then pass to get a database object:

```
getData(id) {

  this.cdQ = this.db.object('/ftuserprofiles/' + this.id);
  this.person = this.cdQ.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(c => {
                    const data = c.payload.val();
                    const id = c.payload.key;
                    return { id, data };
    }));


  this.details = JSON.stringify(this.person);
}
```

I put them together as simple calls as such:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad GardenPage');
    this.getUID();
    this.getData(this.uid2);
}
```

This does not work - returns a null object. However, if I take the same getData() call with the full path, it returns the correct values.

```
getData() {

  this.cdQ = this.db.object('/ftuserprofiles/bc40165a-f275-60af-74af-bfa33137c9fc');
  this.person = this.cdQ.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(c => {
                    const data = c.payload.val();
                    const id = c.payload.key;
                    return { id, data };
    }));


  this.details = JSON.stringify(this.person);
}
```

Output looks like a JSON object using

#### ```
{{ person | async | json }}
```

```
{
  "id": "bc40165a-f275-60af-74af-bfa33137c9fc",
  "data": {
    "address": "555 S. 1st St, Petaluma, CA 95444",
    "bedmap": [
      {
        "inProgress": false,
        "path": "files/d2c8eb15-7644-a232-78e4-c843955ed872-Screenshot_20181004-073408.png",
        "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/avaapp-db.appspot.com/o/files%2Fd2c8eb15-7644-a232-78e4-c843955ed872-Screenshot_20181004-073408.png?alt=media&token=4bcbea0b-2a62-430e-b1ef-e73f0f86bf06"
      }
    ],
    "bio": "Test user",
    "countries": [
      "Sonoma"
    ],
    "email": "j@j.com",
    "email2": "jay@nnn.com",
    "firstName": "Jay",
    "hardware": [
      "Classic"
    ],
    "lastName": "Nnn",
    "numbeds": "4",
    "phoneNumber": "4153333321",
    "plantingdate": 1538665304000,
    "service": [
      "Remote"
    ],
    "startdate": 1538406104000,
    "title": "Jay Nnn"
  }
}
```

The question I have is why would it not work with the original method & are there any good ways to display a single field?

I've tried setting the variables in the .ts file (this.address = this.person.address) and in the html i've tried as a list:

```
<li *ngFor="let fields of person | async | keyvalue">
   {{fields}} 
</li>
```

or as a specific field call out:

```
{{person.address | async}}
```

or

```
{{person.data.address}}
```

or

```
{{person['data']['address']}}
```

and can't get anything to work

Answer (score 1):

`this.uid2` is assigned only if the promise resolves in `getUID`. So you have an async behavior but you do not wait for the response, so when you pass `this.uid2` to `getData`, `this.uid2` is not assigned.

Better approach if you return promise in `getUID` and you call `getData` in `then`.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that (Promises seem so simple that I don't know where I am going wrong) and it just returns null. Is there anything obvious I've missed? 

Updated StackBlitz [link](https://angular-firetortbexample.stackblitz.io)

Resource for Promise setup [link](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/callbacks-promises-and-async-await-ad4756e01d90)